# Keep geting a jQuery syntax error please

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My code has been working flawlessly but from Thursday I'm getting an syntax error in firebug and the uplodify is not working the error reads as,

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list [Break On This Error]
>
> });
>
> jquery.min.js (line 2, col 4)

I don't have clue whats wrong and it's giving the error on the jQuery not in my code I replaced my changed codes with the original which was working but still m getting this error. I'm using the GOOGLE link and I downgraded to if it works but it didn't same error over and over.

Below is my script where jQuery is used,

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('lId.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Upl/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
            'auto'     : false,
            'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
            'height'   : 20,
            'width'    : 200,
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
    }
        // Put your options here
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#save_data").click(function(){
    var name  = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("Descrip").value;
    var con = document.getElementById("ConInfo").value;

    var dataString = 'Name='+name+'&Descrip='+desc+'&ConInfo='+con;
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:dataString,
      url:'AddPoiPro.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="Data inserted") {
          //alert("Data  Success");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: #060\">Data Saved</dive>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();
        } else {
          //alert("Not Inserted");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: red\">Data Not Saved</div>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();
        }
     } 
   });
  });
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Upl/uploadify.css" />

<title>AddPOI</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="poiid">ID :</label>
    <input type="text" name="poiid" id="poiid" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $tId; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Name">POI Name :</label>

    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Descrip" style="alignment-adjust:middle">POI Description :</label>
    <textarea name="Descrip" id="Descrip" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ConInfo">Contact Infomation :</label>
    <textarea name="ConInfo" id="ConInfo" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Img">POI Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="imgUpload" id="imgUpload" />
  </p>
  <p><div id="msg"></div></p>
  <p>  
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="sendData" value="Submit" onclick="$('#imgUpload').uploadify('upload','*');" style="width:100px;" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Rest Data" style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me I'm stuck with it please.

Comment: You're missing a `)` right before `// Put your options here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
$(function() {
    $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
        'auto'     : false,
        'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
        'height'   : 20,
        'width'    : 200,
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png' // No comma here. Will break older IE
    }); // <-------- Missing paren here.
});
```

Also, like my example, you don't need to nest DOM ready events like that.

Comment: Thank you that was the error I can't imagine I over looked that thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **)** near

```
};
            // Put your options here
```

add it and try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
            'auto'     : false,
            'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
            'height'   : 20,
            'width'    : 200,
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
    });
        // Put your options here
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thx this helped damn how did I miss that thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
   'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
}
```

use this , there `);` missing

```
   'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imgUpload').uploadify({
            'auto'     : false,
            'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
            'height'   : 20,
            'width'    : 200,
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
   }
```

I could think of one ......... Remove the last "," after *.png in above code ... might just help

and another is missing ");" in above snippet at the end

Answer (score 0):

You done small mistake at

```
$(function() {
$('#imgUpload').uploadify({
    'auto'     : false,
    'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
    'height'   : 20,
    'width'    : 200,
    'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png'
  }
 );    //Here you need to add this
```

});

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just this:

```
$(function() { // <---------------------------just one doc ready handler
    $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
        'auto'     : false,
        'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
        'height'   : 20,
        'width'    : 200,
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png' //<-----removed ","
     }); //<--------------------------------------); added this
    // Put your options here
});
```

no need to call `doc ready` handler two times and do some amends those may be your typo here.